# When ever I check whether service is Running in android it always says no

Tags: android, service

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Services.class);
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (Services.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Service is Running",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Service Will run now",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startService(intent);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And Service code

```
package gcmtutorial.androidbegin.com.socket;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by shuser on 21-07-2016.
 */
public class Services extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public class Hello implements Runnable{
        public void run(){
            synchronized (this){
                int i=0;
                while (i<100){
                    try {
                        wait(1000);
                        i++;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Hello());
        thread.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I close the app and starts again It always says Service Will run now. Even my service is running in background. How can i know whether the service is running or not in background in android

Answer (score 1):

I have slightly change the code the reason is below,

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
    if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

> You are putting toast here,and it takes a time, i.e. another toast appears only after first one is gone, try above function with Log not toast.

**Another approach:**

Let's make thing simpler.

1. Create global class.
2. Put one  public static boolean variable.
3. When service starts change the value of this boolean to TRUE.
4. Change the value of this variable to FASLE in onDestroy() of service.
5. Now when you want to check the status then just check this boolean variable from global class.

Comment: @SumitMarwha  happy to know that,yr wlcm. If this really works then kindly accept this answer so other programmers get benefit of this.